# Accessing Notification's RemoteView contents

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, remoteview, notification-listener

I'm trying to list all active notifications on an Android device, by going through their textual fields and extras. For most notifications, that works fine - but for some apps, all these fields (such as title, subtext and so on) are all empty/null. These problematic notifications show empty even on [Android's notifications log screen](https://www.howtogeek.com/242073/how-to-view-notifications-youve-dismissed-on-android/), and in apps like [Notification Saver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pghant.notifsaver).

For example, see this custom-made notification by ES File Explorer app:
[image]

I've come to the conclusion that the reason might be that these specific notifications are probably using a custom RemoteView for their contentView (as explained [here](https://androidheight.blogspot.co.il/2017/04/custom-notification-with-remoteview-in.html)), without setting the other textual fields. My notification listener could access fields that might be relevant, such as `statusBarNotification.getNotification().contentView` and `statusBarNotification.getNotification().bigContentView`, but couldn't find any read/get functions there.

So my question is - can I somehow read the contents of these custom/remote views of a given notification? Perhaps inspect it during runtime? Or if I know a specific viewId that I'm looking for within that view?

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @NoumanCh Unfortunately no :( But thanks for the vote-up!

Comment: there must be some way become few apps are doing this.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.siempo.phone&hl=en

Comment: @NoumanCh are you sure they really are doing what I'm looking for? Or perhaps you only checked with apps that populate the text-based fields behind the scenes? Can you give examples for which apps' notifications are reflected in that app - but can't be read through code (the way I quoted in my original question) please?

Comment: you can check by your self dear but what i saw was it was showing even gmail grouped notifications as perfectly as it would be .

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what the question is about exactly. Gmail's notifications have all (or at least most) of the data in the regular text fields, like they should be.